# Android: Interrupt thread contained in a method

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio, I have a thread contained in a method like so(seen below) because I would like to **restart the thread whenever it is called**[1] ,(recreating the thread rather than restarting)

```
public void callthread(){

   final Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
   {
       @Override
       public void run()
       {
           for (int x=0; x<750&&!Thread.interrupted(); x++) {
               //using this and thread sleep for repeated timed code within a thread

               try {
                   Thread.sleep(4);
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                   {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {

                           //some code

                           if (condition) {      
                               myThread.interrupt();
                           }
                       }
                   });

               } catch (InterruptedException e) {

               }
           }
       }
   });
```

My problem is that it wont let me use `myThread.interrupt();` in the desired location in my code, giving me an error saying "variable 'myThread' may not have been initialized" and will not compile because of this. However it works when the entire thread is contained in class but I do not have a way of restarting it. In other words, **I need a way to interrupt the thread while it is contained in a method.**[2]

Accepted Solutions

<s>[1]. **A solution where the thread can be restarted**</s>

[2]. **A solution where the thread can be interrupted while the thread is contained in a method**

PS: If its unclear, I have edited my code above for easy readability but I have not removed things like the `for` loop or the `Thread.sleep` as I assume they could be part of the problem. So if theres too many or too little of a certain curly bracket then thats not the problem

EDIT: Searched around and apparently you cant restart a thread

Comment: `interrupted` is useless. especially if you call it from within the thread. just `return` from run and the thread stops. java won't let you use `myThread` here because it does not know that the `run` is not called until after the init phase is done and the variable actually has a value. but anyway you don't need it.

Comment: also, use `wait`+`notify` instead of `sleep` + `interrupt`

Comment: `for (int x=0; x<750; x++) {

               try {
                   Thread.sleep(4);
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                   {

                       @Override

                       public void run() {

                           //vague image view x +1 


                           if (true) {

                               return;

                           }

                       }


                   });



               }`

vague image view still moves right (unless i need notify+wait for it to work,though im just using interrupt to end the thread)

Comment: What you want to do is already available in the Java language, see [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29).

Comment: The documentation is a little confusing, could you elaborate?

Comment: This `ExecutorService` hangs on to a single thread until you call its [`shutdown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) method which releases the thread. Essentially it does the same as a normal `new Thread().start()` would do, but it doesn't destroy the thread at the end of the task you submit. The submitted tasks can be cancelled making the next one run. If this isn't what you want, please tell me more about your concept.

Comment: Essentially this was used to move an imageview smoothly into different directions, however there seems to be quite a demand for the specific problem. New thread calls were used because the was a different direction each time, while the starting point also may or may not change.

Comment: If you want to do something like start a thread and make it do certain things at random times without actually recreating the thread, `ExecutorService` is still good because you can cancel a submitted and executing task at any time (though it's not guaranteed that it will stop, obviously it depends on your code). If you want to move an `ImageView` around, you should consider using a [property animator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

Comment: The bounty is still available, given the right explanation and syntax/code, I can award it to you

Comment: Why don't you try with an AsyncTask instead of a thread and try to cancel() it. Inside the task you can check if it was cancelled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start the interrupting thread in `myThread` before entering the for-loop. The interrupting thread sleeps 5 seconds and then interrupts `myThread`. The interrupt is handled in the exception handler. There the loop variable `x` is reset to `0`, which is practically a restart of the loop.

```
public class ThreadInterruptRestart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadInterruptRestart().callthread();
    }

    public void callthread() {

        final Thread myThread = new Thread("myThread") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Thread _this = this;

                Thread interruptingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // this is not the interrupt we are interested in
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (true) {
                            System.out.println("interrupting " + _this + " from thread " + this);
                            _this.interrupt();
                        }
                    }
                }, "interrupting thread");
                interruptingThread.start();

                for (int x = 0; x < 750; x++) {
                    // using this and thread sleep for repeated timed code
                    // within a thread
                    try {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        // this is the interrupt we want to handle
                        System.out.println("" + this + " interrupted!");
                        // reset the loop counter
                        x = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

And another version where `myThread` does not sleep, and synchronization is used instead of an `InterruptedException`:

```
public class ThreadInterruptRestart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadInterruptRestart().callthread();
    }

    public void callthread() {

        final Object mutex = new Object();

        final Thread myThread = new Thread("myThread") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Thread _this = this;

                Thread interruptingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // this is not the interrupt we are interested in
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (true) {
                            System.out.println("interrupting " + _this + " from thread " + this);
                            synchronized (mutex) {
                                _this.interrupt();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, "interrupting thread");
                interruptingThread.start();

                for (int x = 0; x < 75000; x++) {
                    // using this and thread sleep for repeated timed code
                    // within a thread
                    synchronized (mutex) {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        // do other stuff here
                    }
                    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                        // this is the interrupt we want to handle
                        System.out.println("" + this + " interrupted!");
                        // reset the loop counter
                        x = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways of ending the thread. However if you have to  access the thread use a reference variable like this:

```
 public void callthread(){

   final Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
   {
       @Override
       public void run()
       {
           final Thread _this = this;
           for (int x=0; x<750&&!Thread.interrupted(); x++) {
               //using this and thread sleep for repeated timed code within a thread

               try {
                   Thread.sleep(4);
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                   {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {

                           //some code

                           if (condition) {      
                               _this.interrupt();
                           }
                       }
                   });

               } catch (InterruptedException e) {

               }
           }
       }
   });
```

Comment: still wont let me restart :/

Answer (score 1):

The flaw in your code is "Leaking of this constructor" where you try to call the object's (in your case) thread's method before the thread has been instantiated.

To solve this you can go for a design similar to Observer pattern

Answer (score 1):

Is this of any use?

As a side note, `runOnUiThread` is quite a code smell and can lead to some quite subtle timing bugs. What are you using it for? It's also very hard to tell what you are trying to achieve here. Using something like an executor may simplify things considerably.

```
public void callthread()
{

    final Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            final Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
            for (int x = 0; x < 750 && !Thread.interrupted(); x++)
            {
                //using this and thread sleep for repeated timed code within a thread

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(4);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {

                            //some code

                            if (true)
                            {
                                thread.interrupt();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue is that you're getting lost in nested task classes. Another part is that you're trying too hard to use the threading mechanism to do your logical control. So make your classes control themselves and keep your threading model simple.

**`ParallelTask`**

```
/**
 * An implementation of your inner Runnable.
 */
public class ParallelTask implements Runnable
{
    protected ParallelTaskRunner m_runner = null ;

    private ParallelTask() {} // Disallow default constructor.

    public ParallelTask( ParallelTaskRunner runner )
    { m_runner = runner ; }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // The code from that original inner class.
        if( /* trigger condition */ )
            m_runner.stop(this) ;
    }
}
```

**`ParallelTaskRunner`**

```
/**
 * An implementation of the outer class.
 */
public class ParallelTaskRunner implements Runnable
{
    public static final int THREAD_COUNT = 750 ;

    protected boolean m_bRunning = false ;
    protected ParallelTask m_tskStopper = null ;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if( m_bRunning ) return ; // Don't run if already running.
        m_bRunning = true ; m_tskStopper = null ;
        for( int i = 0 ; i < THREAD_COUNT && m_bRunning ; i++ )
        {
            try
            {
                // Insert some wait interval here if desired.
                (new Thread( new ParallelTask(this) )).run() ;
            }
            catch( Exception x )
            {
                Log.w( "ParallelTaskRunner.run()",
                       "Caught exception.", x ) ;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stop( ParallelTask tsk )
    {
        m_bRunning = false ;
        if( m_tskStopper == null )
            m_tskStopper = tsk ;
    }

    public ParallelTask getStopper()
    { return m_tskStopper ; }
}
```

**And then, in some consumer class...**

```
public void callThreads()
{
    ParallelTaskRunner runner = new ParallelTaskRunner() ;
    (new Thread(runner)).run() ;
}
```

In the `callThread()` method you can then display reports based on the data contained in `runner`. For example, if you have the threads uniquely identify themselves with a UUID or simple integer (the index of the loop?), then your application could display a toast with the "stopper" task's ID. If the code you're executing in `ParallelTask` writes out interesting data, then that data can be made available through accessors in `ParallelTask`, which you'd then call by first calling `runner.getStopper()` and then operating on that `ParallelTask` instance.