# How would i make imageView rolling in from bottom left corner to the bottom right corner?

Tags: android, animation

Does anyone know how would i do this? And imageView should come from outside of the activity.

Here is the code:

rollingImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

```
AnimationSet rollingIn = new AnimationSet(true);

Animation moving = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,-1f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
moving.setDuration(5000);

rollingIn.addAnimation(moving);

Animation rotating = new RotateAnimation(0, 720, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotating.setDuration(5000);

rollingIn.addAnimation(rotating);

rollingImageView.startAnimation(rollingIn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your imageview set to the bottom left down, (this will only help you go from left to right)

In your activity file...

```
public void callthismethodtostartrolling(){




   final Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
   {
       @Override
       public void run()
       {              
           while (!<imageviewInRightCorner>) {//<<define this yourself

               try {
                   Thread.sleep(4);
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                   {

                       @Override

                       public void run() {

                           rollingImageView.setX((float) (rollingImageView.getX() + 5));

                     }

                   });
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   // this should not happen
               }

           }
       }
   });

myThread.start
}
```

**PROS**

I think it gives the effect you want.

**CONS**

Ive tried this before, it works, but you cant interrupt the Thread inside the Thread if you ever need to do so. The link to the original problem/con of this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930130/android-interrupt-thread-contained-in-a-method),if you would like to help Dusan and I ._.

**ALTERNATIVE**

```
final Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
   {
       @Override
       public void run()
       {              
           while (!<imageviewInRightCorner>) {//<<define this yourself

               try {
                   Thread.sleep(4);
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                   {

                       @Override

                       public void run() {

                           rollingImageView.setX((float) (rollingImageView.getX() + 5));

                     }

                   });
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   // this should not happen
               }

           }
       }
   });
```

Using `myThread.start` anywhere in your code to activate your sliding imageview awesomeness.

**PROS**

Alternative to first option with a different con to suit your need

*able to use `myThread.interrupt` within Thread

**CONS**

Cant call the Thread more than once per launch :/ the reason why is all in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930130/android-interrupt-thread-contained-in-a-method)

potential while condition explained(as requested by asker)...

[image]

Comment: Sorry for answering now. Thank you for this detail answer, but i'm new in android developing and this is probably a stupid question, but what should i define after `while`?

Comment: If you are transporting your imageview to the bottom left corner with a specific XY (not compatible across devices) Then `while (rollingImageView.getX()==<X coordinate of select width of screen>)` of course this is different across devices so if you want, you can  `while (rollingImageView.getX()==maxX - <half the width of your imageview>)`

Comment: continueation... after of course defining maxX...
`Display mdisp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();                          
                int maxX= mdisp.getWidth();`

Comment: yes the `while (rollingImageView.getX()==<X coordinate of select width of screen>)` tells the system to continue adding to the imageviews X coordinate (moving it to the right) until the imageviews x coordinate reaches the end of your screen, or a select spot along the X-Axis you want. maxX was just a suggestion if you wanted to get the exact right end of the users screen across different devices. I apologize if my comments are a little confusing

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't working. I can't define X coordinate of ImageView. Could we continue this disccussion to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87534/discussion-between-dusan-dimitrijevic-and-hisownmother).